Angular : Translate dynamic variable value in angular
I have implemented multi language translation in angular for selected static words (as this project have google translation API already implemented for translations, but for some words client is asking for different translations as it is not correct according to them) using a json file which have translations mentioned like below:
{
  "Sign In": {
    "en": "Sign In",
    "nl": "Inloggen",
    "fr": "Se connecter",
    "de": "Anmeldung"
  }
}

Created a language service.ts file like below:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LanguageService {

  public translations: any;
  private langSubject = new Subject<any>();
  langSubject$= this.langSubject.asObservable()

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
       this.loadTranslations().subscribe(translations => {
       this.translations = translations;
   });
}

loadTranslations(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>('../assets/words.json').pipe(
    tap((translations: any) => {
       this.translations = translations;
     })
   );
 }

 declareLangChange(lang: any){
   this.langSubject.next(lang)
 }

 translate(key: string, lang: string): string {
  if (!this.translations) return '';
    const defaultTranslation = (this.translations[key]?.en || ''); // English translation
    return this.translations[key]?.[lang] || defaultTranslation;
  }
}

in main component called translator function on ngOnit():
this.ls.langSubject$.subscribe((lang:any)=>{
    this.selectedLang=lang;
})

translateWord(key: string): string {
    return this.ls.translate(key, this.selectedLang);
}

in html file passed static word which needs to be translated in function:
{{ translateWord('Sign In') }}

Now I need to **

translate values form data coming dynamically from API

**. I am getting object of color names among which I only need to translate one color name which is incorrectly translated.
The function below calls an api and stores response in multiple variables, one of which is colorList. In the response stored in this variable, we have "GREEN" color which we need to custom translate just like we did for static words.
getSideFilterData(category_id: any) {
    let body = {
    id: category_id,
    buyer_country: this.gs.loginData.country || ''
}


this.gs.getSidebarFilterData(body).subscribe(async (resp: any) => {
  if (resp['status']) {
    for (let j in resp.colors) {
      resp.colors[j] = {
        color: resp.colors[j]
      }
    }

    
    for (let j in resp.brands) {
      if (resp.brands[j].brand_id == this.cartBrandId) {
        resp.brands[j].isCheckedBrand = true;
      }
    }

      // Filter Array
      this.brandList = resp.brands;
      this.colorsList = resp.colors;
      this.colorFamily = resp.colorFamily;
      this.finishTypeList = resp.finishType;
      this.materialTypeList = resp.materialType;
    } else {
      this.brandList = [];
      this.colorsList = [];
      this.colorFamily = [];
      this.finishTypeList = [];
      this.materialTypeList = [];
    }

  }, (error: any) => {
    console.log('error', error);
  });
}

Any help would be appreciated on translating dynamic values. Thanks in advance!

bad practice load all translations from one file. if u france - load just france, if germany - load german


1 translate file per language

in html templates use pipe translate (variable | translate)

app.module.ts
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

export class TranslateHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
  handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
    /* some logic */
  }
}

export function appInitializerFactory(translateService: TranslateService, injector: Injector): () => Promise<any> {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
  return () => new Promise<any>((resolve: any) => {
    const locationInitialized = injector.get(LOCATION_INITIALIZED, Promise.resolve(null));
    locationInitialized.then(() => {
      translateService.use(localStorage.getItem("language") || window.navigator.language) // here u can change language loaded before reander enything
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe(() => {},
        err => console.error(err), () => resolve(null));
    });
  });
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
                deps: [HttpClient]
            },
            isolate: false,
            missingTranslationHandler: [{provide: MissingTranslationHandler, useClass: TranslateHandler}]
        }),
    ]
    providers: [
        ...,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
            deps: [TranslateService, Injector],
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}


in module of your component add TranslationModule

in component constructor public ts: TranslateService) {}

now u can use:
this.ts.instant('YOUR_KEY'); // return translated string or your key if translation not founded, but u can change logic in TranslateHandler


all translations stored in assets/i18n/. for example en.json



thank you for your reply, i forgot to mention that we are using google API for translation its just for some selected words we need different translation which is why we have customized like this. We don't want to implement localization this way.
